# JQuery - radio button CSS not refreshing after submit

Tags: html, css, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with twitter bootstrap buttons as below

```
  <label class="control-label span3">Status of the Dispute? </label>
<div class="controls span7">
<label class="inline radio">  
<input type="radio" id="status" name="status" value="Continue"/> Continue</label>
<label class="inline radio">
 <input type="radio" id="status"  name="status" value="Resolved"/>Resolved</label>
<label class="inline radio">
<input type="radio" id="status"  name="status" value="Referred"/> Referred</label>
 <label for="status" class="error">Please tell us the dispute status</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Upon submission, the form submits the data successfully and refreshes well all other elements except the radio buttons.

I've searched for various options, and came along prop function. It helped me to somepoint as it unchecks the selector on the inside. CSS stylsheet on the user page still remain as if it is selected.

```
  $('input[name="status"]').prop('checked', false);
```

I also tried this idea

```
$('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("inline radio");
```

but its still not successfull.

My full submit code is as follows:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({

  submitHandler: function(form) {

            $.post('registermyform.php',
            $("#registermyform").serialize(),
            function(data) 
            {
            $('#results').html(data);   
            if (data="yes"){
             alert("The new Dispute has been successfully submitted!");
               $('#registerDispute')[0].reset();

                $('input[name="status"]').prop('checked', false);       

               $('input:checked').parent().removeClass("inline radio");

            }
            else    {
            alert("not submitted!");
                    } 
            });
        }
});
```

Please assist. I want to remove the CSS of radio buttons such that it doesn't appear as if it is checked while it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the elements to reset them all:

```
var $items = $('input[name="status"]');
for (var i = 0; i < $items.length; i++) {
    $($items[i]).prop('checked', false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ricaldo, however its still not working! prop('checked', false) actually unchecks the radio in the inside. However the CSS in the page does not dispappear. Because when I try to resubmit the radio buttons are submitted as unchecked!

Comment: Please update the question to reflect what do you actually look for.

Comment: Are you assigning CSS styles when the radio btn is selected?